# RSpec -- Object *should* be created once but is instead created for each test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec, rspec2

I'm trying to build rspec (rspec2) test cases for a helper i'm developing. This helper basically does some stuff with "Signal" objects.  In my app a "Signal" is associated to an "Author".

The trouble I'm having here is that when i test using code like this:

```
describe SignalHelper do
  let(:author) { Author.create(author_identifier: "foobar_identifier") }

  specify "should fail to instantiate without an author" do
    lambda { SignalHelper.new }.should raise_error
  end

  specify "should instantiate with a valid author" do
    SignalHelper.new(author)
  end
end
```

I'm finding that multiple authors are being created and indirectly causing issues for the code in SignalHelper.

What can i do to create ONE Author before all of the tests run and use that same author in each test?

I thought that using `let()` was the correct approach but this is obviously not the case.  I've also tried code that looked similar to this with no success:

```
describe SignalHelper do
  let(:author) { Author.create(author_identifier: "foobar_identifier") }

  before(:all) do 
    author
  end

  specify "should fail to instantiate without an author" do
    lambda { SignalHelper.new }.should raise_error
  end

  specify "should instantiate with a valid author" do
    SignalHelper.new(author)
  end
end
```

Thank you!

Comment: Instantiating a helper with another object seems a little fishy. Maybe there's a better approach to what you're trying to do. If you're interested in exploring that, you could post your helper code as well.

Comment: Beerlington, unfortunately i'm not at liberty to post it and i hacked this code that "represents" my issue together.  I think the core issue is that i'm not sure how to approach using the same object in all of my tests, rather than creating a new instance of it for every single test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using #let is the correct approach as it makes sure you don't share the state of your test objects between spec examples. If you can't create multiple authors for whatever reason, then just create one as an ivar:

```
describe SignalHelper do
  before(:all) { @author = Author.create(author_identifier: "foobar_identifier") }

  specify "should fail to instantiate without an author" do
    lambda { SignalHelper.new }.should raise_error
  end

  specify "should instantiate with a valid author" do
    SignalHelper.new(@author)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

See http://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/transactions.

Comment: Hi David, thank you for the link.  I actually was using database_cleaner but removed it and set rspec back to `config.use_transactional_fixtures = true` to try and isolate the issue but still no dice.  Should i be concerned that i'm using `specify` rather than `it` in combination with `config.use_transactional_fixtures = true` ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case the `database_cleaner` gem was deleting the records after each test, so `let()` was recreating them.

`config.after(:each) { DatabaseCleaner.clean }`